# How to jump to a non empty line in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, shortcut

I have edited my shortcuts for ST3 to jump to the next empty line:

```
// Jump to empty line
,{ "keys": ["ctrl+up"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "stops", "empty_line": true, "forward": false} }
,{ "keys": ["ctrl+down"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "stops", "empty_line": true, "forward": true} } 
// Select to empty line
,{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+up"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "stops", "empty_line": true, "forward": false, "extend": true} }
,{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+down"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "stops", "empty_line": true, "forward": true, "extend": true} }
```

How can I adapt these shortcuts in the context of being on an empty line jumping to the next non-empty line and vice-versa?

My problem is, that I don't know how to jump to a non-empty line and also, that I don't know how I should use context.

```
context: "non_empty_line" my code above
context: "empty_line" ...?
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried the simple solution of `"empty_line": false`?

Comment: Sounds logical :-) Thank you! Still I don't know how to make it case specific (i.e. my context related issue)...

Comment: No, that doesn't work. `{ "keys": ["ctrl+down"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "stops", "empty_line": false, "forward": true} }` makes the selector jump to the end of my file...